# jQuery Gallery won't work in any version of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I wrote my original jQuery code and saw that it wasn't working in any version of IE.

I used JSLint to figure out why it wasn't working in any version of internet explorer.

Here is my new code that I cleaned up using JSLint http://theburnmachinept.com/js/scripts.js.

This still refuses to work on any version of IE. AND to top it off it doesn't work on any browser now. I switched back to the ORIGINALscripts.js file for the time being. Can anyone find anything wrong with my code? The code in question is the gallery code that starts on line 17 and ends on line 126.

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could offer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `$('#image').hide();` causes it, try `$('#image').fadeOut();`